# How could this PendingIntent alarm cancelled?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I've managed to understand this code. This code is used in an reminder app. What this code do is to set and cancel alarm. However, i don't know how the newly created reference could cancel existing PendingIntent. Please explain me this code (the execute method).

Here's the code:

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "AlarmService";

    public static final String POPULATE = "POPULATE";
    public static final String CREATE = "CREATE";
    public static final String CANCEL = "CANCEL";

    private IntentFilter matcher;

    public AlarmService() {
        super(TAG);
        matcher = new IntentFilter();
        matcher.addAction(POPULATE);
        matcher.addAction(CREATE);
        matcher.addAction(CANCEL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String alarmId = intent.getStringExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID);
        String alarmMsgId = intent.getStringExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ID);
        String startTime = intent.getStringExtra(Alarm.COL_FROMDATE);
        String endTime = intent.getStringExtra(Alarm.COL_TODATE);

        if (matcher.matchAction(action)) {
            if (POPULATE.equals(action)) {
                RemindMe.dbHelper.populate(Long.parseLong(alarmId), RemindMe.db);
                execute(CREATE, alarmId);
            }

            if (CREATE.equals(action)) {
                execute(CREATE, alarmId, alarmMsgId, startTime, endTime);
            }

            if (CANCEL.equals(action)) {
                execute(CANCEL, alarmId, alarmMsgId, startTime, endTime);
                RemindMe.dbHelper.shred(RemindMe.db);
            }           
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param action
     * @param args {alarmId, alarmMsgId, startTime, endTime}
     */ 
    private void execute(String action, String... args) {       
        Intent i;
        PendingIntent pi;               
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Cursor c;

        String alarmId = (args!=null && args.length>0) ? args[0] : null;
        String alarmMsgId = (args!=null && args.length>1) ? args[1] : null;
        String startTime = (args!=null && args.length>2) ? args[2] : null;
        String endTime = (args!=null && args.length>3) ? args[3] : null;

        String status = CANCEL.equals(action) ? AlarmMsg.CANCELLED : AlarmMsg.ACTIVE;

        if (alarmMsgId != null) {
            c = RemindMe.db.query(AlarmMsg.TABLE_NAME, null, AlarmMsg.COL_ID+" = ?", new String[]{alarmMsgId}, null, null, null);

        } else {
            c = AlarmMsg.list(RemindMe.db, alarmId, startTime, endTime, status);
        }

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long time, diff;
//          long count = c.getCount();
//          double MAX = alarmId!=null && count>30 ? Util.MONTH : Util.YEAR; 
            do {
                i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                i.putExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ID, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(AlarmMsg.COL_ID)));
                i.putExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID)));

                pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//              pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, intent, flags);

                time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME));
                diff = time-now + (long)Util.MIN;
                if (CREATE.equals(action)) {
                    if (diff > 0 && diff < Util.YEAR)
                        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
                    //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, interval, operation);

                } else if (CANCEL.equals(action)) {
                    am.cancel(pi);
                }                       
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code cancels the alarm like this:

```
            } else if (CANCEL.equals(action)) {
                am.cancel(pi);
```

This doesn't cancel the `PendingIntent`, it just cancels the alarm.

This code will never set more than one alarm, because attempts to set a second alarm will automatically cancel the first one. This is because the same `PendingIntent` is used every time.

Comment: Now i get it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Alarm Manager is a SystemService . You can access it from any context and if you have the pending intent from which you started the Alarm. You can Cancel it from that pendingIntent.
Just take a look at the documentation
[Link to Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: But, the PendingIntent retrieved from the do-while loop points to the same PendingIntent every iteration. at PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), the request code is 0 every iteration. this shouldn't cancel or set a different alarm time. Could you explain this?

Comment: if (alarmMsgId != null) {
            c = RemindMe.db.query(AlarmMsg.TABLE_NAME, null, AlarmMsg.COL_ID+" = ?", new String[]{alarmMsgId}, null, null, null);

        } else {
            c = AlarmMsg.list(RemindMe.db, alarmId, startTime, endTime, status);
        }
By this portion I can guess if there is any specific alarm ID it will return only one row and hence will cancel one alarm else it will return list of rows having alarm set from start to end time given and cursor's (moveToNext()) will iterate thorough all rows in that time span and cancel all the alarms between that time.